# how can i update height jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have embed code, the code embed has a original height of 300px but after few seconds it changes its height randomly depending of the parameters I am using.

this is the code (The web page is an example)

```
$( <embed></embed>) .attr("src", "http://www.bbs.com")
                    .attr('id', 'bbs_embed')
                    .attr('width', 1440)
                    .attr('height', 300)
                    .appendTo("body")
                    ;
```

after 7 seconds more or less, height changes to 1500px or more (randomly)

How can I update its height (from 300 to the new height) using javascript / Jquery?

Comment: give it an ID, call that ID, change the height. Otherwise you're just continuously recreating a new embed element.

Comment: I'd recomend you to  use the [css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/), and create the element on HTML (hidden if needed) and then modify it.

Comment: Enable overflow scroll for embed element and set max-height as well.

Comment: How will you get the new height ?

Comment: @Jhecht inside the embed content i have an ID, but it doesnt update the height. it's like not reading the id from embed code.

Comment: @Ali Khanusiya that's what i need, how can i get the new height?

Comment: @pratikwebdev i tried it but didnt work

Comment: New height means which height ?

Comment: @AliKhanusiya I have two height, the first one is 300px, the second one is randomly, i need the second one, i can get the second one after 10 seconds, but i dont know how i can get it, do you understand me?

Comment: @MrPibe You told that you can get second height after 10 second. So then what you need to get?

Comment: @AliKhanusiya i need to know how i can get that the new height after 10 seconds, what's the code for it?

Comment: @MrPibe So at every 10 seconds you need to get its height ? Is it your requirement ?

Comment: @AliKhanusiya no, only one time. i load the page, wait 10 seconds, get the new height. that's the requerimient. everytime i load the page.

Comment: @MrPibe Once page loading finishes then after 10 secons you need to get new height. Is it?

Comment: @AliKhanusiya yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var ele = $( "<embed></embed>").attr("src", "URL")
                .attr('id', 'bbs_embed')
                .css({ "width": "1440px", "max-height": "300px", "overflow-y" : "scroll", "border":"1px solid black"});

                $("body").append(ele);
     });
```

Comment: Hi. It is not taking me the height :(

Comment: i did not get you. Height is 300px. Is it not showing it correctly?

Comment: when the page loads at the beginning  the height is 300px, after 10 seconds the new height for embed code is randomly, i need to update to the new height, for example 4000px. do you understand me?

Comment: @MrPibe Can you share the screenshot in question. Would like to see if embed element is getting expanded or body itself.